# Building a Java chatbot connected to xml data

Tags: xml, nlp, chatbot

I'm trying to build a chatbot that supports NLP and communicate with XML to answer. Can anyone guide me because I don't know where to start?

Comment: Your question is *incredibly* broad, and there are a lot of opinion-based answers to it. Some research, presenting what you've found, and narrowing down your question will go a long way to getting you started on your project and getting you good answers.